# Как правильно хранить изображения на сервере?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Требуется загрузить изображение в MySQL через форму :

```html
<p>
    <span class='ttl'>Постер<span style="color:red;">*</span></span>
    <span class='fld'>
<input id='picture' type='file' charset="base64" placeholder="example@email.com" class="field"/>
</span>
</p>
```

Код загрузки:

```php
<?php
// Устанавливаем соединение с базой данных
require_once("connect.php");
try {
// 1. Проверяем, переданы ли POST-параметры;
// если ответ положительный, помещаем новое
// сообщение в базу данных
    if(!empty($_POST))
    {
        $error = [];
        if(empty($_POST['creator'])) {
            $error[] = "Отсутствует автор статьи";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['title'])) {
            $error[] = "Отсутствует название статьи";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['picture'])) {
            $error[] = "Отсутствует постер статьи";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['category'])) {
            $error[] = "Отсутствует категория статьи";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['text_paper'])) {
            $error[] = "Отсутствует текст статьи";
        }
// Если нет ошибок, помещаем сообщение
// в базу данных
        if(empty($error))
        {
            $query = "INSERT INTO
paper
VALUES (
:category,
:creator,
NOW(),
:title,
:text_paper,
:picture,
NULL)";
            $usr = $pdo->prepare($query);
            $usr->execute([
                'category' => $_POST['category'],
                'creator' => $_POST['creator'],
                'title' => $_POST['title'],
                'text_paper' => $_POST['text_paper'],
                'picture' => $_POST['picture'],
            ]);
        }
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Ошибка выполнения запроса: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Если грузить изображение через PhpMyAdmin то все работает корректно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если грузить через форму на сайте, то выводит следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изображения хранятся в формате BLOB, единственный способ что нашел на просторах интернета основывается на этом, при том что большие изображения грузить не представляется возможным. Если есть (наверняка) более лучший способ реализовать загрузку/выгрузку в/из MySQL буду рад ссылкам на ресурсы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Пошаговый, быстрый гайд, по хранению изображений на сервере

#### 1. HTML форма

За загрузку изображений у нас отвечает `input` с атрибутом `type="file"`, так же существует атрибут `name="foo"`, есть также допольнительные атрибуты, на подобии `required`, или `accept="image\*"`. Создаем форму загрузки изображения:

```html
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myFile" accept="image/*" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

- `method="post"` - Задаем метод отправки `POST`, именно его, следуя спецификации [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3)
- `type="file"` - Задаем тегу `input` тип, в данном случае тип `file`
- `name="file"` - Задаем имя, для того чтобы в PHP потом получить отправленное изображение
- `type="submit"` - Задаем тип тегу `input` как `submit`, он просто сгенерирует кнопку с событием, по нажатию, наша форма отправится на скрипт `upload.php`
- `enctype="multipart/form-data"` - **ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО**, это передача заголовков о загрузке изображения, без нее загрузка работать не будет!!!

Форма для загрузки изображения готова, теперь перейдем к серверной части.

---

#### 2. База данных(MySQL)

Хранить изображения в талице в формате `BLOB` - одна из самых **глупых и плохих** реализаций данной задачи. Поэтому будем хранить **путь**(В дальнейшем `path`) до нашего изображения на сервере. Наша таблица `image` будет иметь такую структуру:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbname.image (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  path VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

- `id` - **Уникальный** индентефикатор картинки
- `path` - **Путь** до нашей картинки на сервере, к примеру `/uploads/image_foobar.jpg`

Подмечу, что путь до нашей картинки должен быть также **уникален**, чтобы не было конфликтов имен, при загрузке одинаковым по имени изображений - этого мы добьемся средствами PHP.

---

#### 3. Скрипт загрузки (Upload.php)

Скрипт будет предельно **простой**, без проверок на уже созданное имя файла и прочее, для подключения к базе будем использовать `PDO` и подготовленные запрос, далее в коде оставил комментарии:

```php
<?php

if($file = $_FILES['myFile']) {

    // Получаем наше изображение, имя которого мы указали в атрибуте `name="file"`

    $path =  __DIR__ . '/uploads/'; // Наш путь до папки загрузок

    $fileExt = end(explode('.', $file['name']));  // Получили расширение файла `jpg`

    $fileName = uniqid('image_') . "." . $fileExt;    // Сгенерировали уникальное имя нашему файлу, с расширением

    try {

        // Создаем экземпляр класса PDO
        $pdo = new PDO(
            'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname',
            'root',
            ''
        );

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO `image`(path) VALUES(?)';   // Создаем SQL-запрос для вставки имени изображения

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);    // Подготавливаем наш запрос
        $stmt->execute([$fileName]);    // Выполняем наш запрос
        move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $path.$fileName); // Сохраняем картинку на сервере в '/uploads/'

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        echo $e->getMessage();

    }

}
```

---

#### 4. Итоги

В данном примере было показана реализация хранения изображений на сервере. Путь для хранения изображений может быть абсолютно любой - это на ваше усмотрение. Изображения можно хранить в формате `BLOB`, но **крайне не рекомендуется**, с этим возникнет много разных проблем, которые вы захотите быстро решить и затыкаете костылями.

Я показал как реализовать самую базовую загрузку и хранение изображений на сервере, ее оптимизация, а также реализация загрузки сразу несколькиз файлов - зависит от вашей фантазии, пробуйте и эксперементируйте. Хорошего вам изучения и программирования). Спасибо большое за прочтение "мини-поста" :)