# Мулти Файл аплоадер, ошибка

Tags: php

Имеется такой код.

```
<form method="post" action="upload-page.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" type="file" multiple="" />
  <input type="submit" name="Stexelnkarnery.">
</form>
```

Содеримое uploader-page.php

```
<?php 

if(count($_FILES['uploads']['filesToUpload'])) {
    foreach ($_FILES['uploads']['filesToUpload'] as $file) {


        echo $file;

    }
} ?>
```

После нажатия на кнопку вылезает ошибка

```
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in upload-page.php on line 3
```

В идеале должна получится кнопка с которой мы можем загуризть 2 или больше картинок сразу, и все они будут падать в какую-то директорию .

Comment: укажите используемый фреймворк и line 3

Comment: line 3 это в php , if(count(.... 
Фреймворк не использую.

Comment: И откуда вообще взялись `$_FILES['uploads']`? Я не вижу ни одного инпута с таким именем.

Comment: Код не мой, не мыслью откуда он появился, можете предложить вашу версию решения проблемы?

Comment: $_FILES['filesToUpload']

Comment: "Ниче не хочу понимать, решите все за меня"

Comment: Я вовсе так не написал.
Не понимаю откуда это появилось, предложите вашу версию, мы сможем понять, почему это было не правильно, и почему ваш вариант лучше.

Comment: Комментарием выше уже предложили.

Comment: Кирилл , ошибка исчезла, но я хотел бы и понять, как все это работает. Если не будет трудно, можете обяснить? Хочу понять как его после в какую нибудь директорию сохранить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы вызываете метод `count()`, который ждет от вас объект или же массив. В вашем случае вы передаете ему `null`, потому что вы передаете `$_FILES['uploads']['filesToUpload']`, Если вы задебажите код, то у вас будет так:

```php
var_dump($_FILES['uploads']['filesToUpload']);  // null
```

Вы передаете `null` в метод `count()`. Получается интерпретатор видит это так:

```php
if(count(null)) {
    // do something...
}
```

Вы создали форму, в которой указали имя `input`, в которое будет происходить загрузка файлов(**момент**: должно быть `multiple="multiple"`):

```html
<input name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

И ваши файлы будут доступны с суперглобальном массиве `$_FILES['filesToUpload']`.

Для того чтобы вам вывести имена загруженных файлов можете сделать так:

```
if ($_FILES['filesToUpload']) {
    foreach ($_FILES['filesToUpload']['name'] as $file) {
        echo $file . "<br>";
    }
}
```

---

Для того чтобы сохранить в директорию можете посмотреть данный ответ, я уже рассказывал как это сделать по шагам, ссылка: [Как правильно хранить изображения на сервере?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1019502/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5/1019508#1019508)

Comment: Прекраснейший ответ, спасибо.